# Digital Circuits Half/Full Adders

Tags: hardware, circuit

I am taking a Digital Circuits class in which we do not use a book, only lecture notes. In the section that covers adders I only have 2 small examples covering addition and subtraction of binary numbers. I am pretty sure i am going to have worded problems in the exam such as design a circuit to count something etc. Does anyone know any sites that have example questions and solution for me to go over?

Comment: You may want to check out Chiphacker.com;  most of the guys over there might be more qualified to answer this question than the folks on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any particular sites, but I do know that when I took a similar class, the lecturer was awful and I relied entirely on the textbook.  It was [Digital Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130621218), by M Morris Mano.  I highly recommend it - it's got plenty of problems to go over and has all the information you need in case you get stuck on something.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29) is a useful resource. The best way to learn electronics is to build your own circuits, preferably with real hardware or using a simulator if the former is not practicable.

P.S. You do not need adders to count events. A cascade of bi-stable flip-flops will do this.